# Can you set the day you will receive a newsletter?

Tags: support, newsletter

I just suscribed to a Newsletter. I immediately got the following email:

> Welcome to the Lifehacks Newsletter!
>
> You will receive the newsletter every Monday.
>
> To subscribe to more newsletters, or manage your existing
> subscriptions, click here.
>
> If the above link is not clickable, copy and paste this link into your
> web browser's address bar:
>
> ```
> https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/<...>&day=monday&confirmed=lifehacks.stackexchange.com
> ```

```
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This makes me wonder:

Can you set up the day in which the newsletter will be sent? I did the test by changing `&day=monday` to `&day=tuesday` and the page that was created shows:

> Thank you for signing up for the Lifehacks Newsletter! You will
> receive the newsletter every **Tuesday**.

However, it still mentions Monday in [my Profile → Subscriptions](https://stackexchange.com/users/2251762/fedorqui?tab=subscriptions).

Answer (score 1):

The `&day=monday` is just a url parameter. It might control the day you get it, or it might just tell the browser what to display on the thank you page.

I suggest you just wait until Monday to find out.

Comment: yep, that is exactly my question: does it really affect the subscription?

Comment: @fedorqui Wait until Monday then :D

Comment: I did some tests and it does not affect my Profile data: http://stackexchange.com/users/2251762/fedorqui?tab=subscriptions